# Can Data Annotations in C# .NET 6 be used to validate API input?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Web API project where a model User class looks like this:

```
public class User
{
   
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "UserName needs to be greater than 3 characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; } ...
```

I have a controller that uses the User model to register a user account:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilterAttribute))]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<int>>> Register(UserRegisterDTO request)
```

and I've added a ServiceFilter with a custom ValidationFilter class:

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    } ...
```

Finally, in my Program.cs, I've added the ValidationFilterAttribute prior to adding my controllers:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ValidationFilterAttribute>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

I've debugged my code and clearly see it going into the OnActionExecuting Filter method but the ModelState.IsValid is always valid, even when I enter a username of 2 characters.

Am I missing something on how this data annotations and validation works? Examples online always seem to imply the validation and error messages appear on the GUI but I had assumed if invalid values were sent in the API payload, it would be detected in this manner and you could return a response that the object can't be processed, along with the details of what failed.

I would like to ensure clean data at the data entry level and not have to explicitly code data validation in the object methods.

Comment: This should work out of the box without even custom filter.

Comment: You are right. Turns out when I moved the Data Annotation from the Model class and onto the DTO being called, it worked without any custom filters implementation. I'm assuming this is due to my Post using the UserRegisterDTO class that I built. I didn't find any specific documentation online, all samples I saw had the data annotation on the model so maybe I'm still missing the point on something... which is why I'm commenting and not answering.

Comment: Yes, validations are applied to the model received. Model received by action is bound against request data and then validated and it does not know anything about other classes.